# Implementing X-fast/Y-fast trie in idiomatic C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm implementing X-fast/Y-fast trie data structures in modern, idiomatic C++, half for fun, half for studying. I want to get help in selecting appropriate sub-data structures for implementation.

X-Fast trie (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-fast_trie) has the following requirements:

[image]

- Integers with k bits are stored in bitwise threaded binary trie. For example, if key is 13 = 1101, we store 1, 11, 110, 1101. 1101 is a leaf.
- For each level, there is a hash table containing all nodes in that level.
- Leaves are connected in a doubly-linked list, in increasing order.
- If an internal node has a missing child, each missing 0 points to its inorder predecessor, and each missing 1 points to its inorder successor.

The first thing that came into my mind is:

```
struct Node {
    std::optional<std::size_t> value;
    std::weak_ptr<Node> parent;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> left;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> right;
};
```

I chose `std::optional<std::size_t>` because the root should not contain a value. I prefer `Node*` for `parent`, and `std::unique_ptr<Node>` for `left/right`, but I had to change this, because the ownership of leaf nodes are shared across multiple ancestors.

For level-search structures:

```
std::array<std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::weak_ptr<Node>>, k>
```

where `k` is a template parameter with type `std::size_t`.

For a linked list for leaves at the bottom layer:

```
std::list<std::weak_ptr<Node>>
```

What I hate here:

- `std::optional`. Is there a better choice to ensure that the root should not contain a value without using `std::optional`? I don't want insane unnecessary overheads for taking care of just a single node.
- The choice of the bottom layer linked list. For a given leaf, I have to access its previous/next leaf. Sure, I can do it by adding `std::weak_ptr<Node> prev` and `std::weak_ptr<Node> next` as member variables for `Node`. But again, I don't want unnecessary overheads for taking care of just the bottom layer. I want to use `std::list<std:weak_ptr<Node>>::iterator`, but how can I get these iterators from leaf pointer `std::weak_ptr<Node>` accessed via the path from the root?

The workaround I thought:

- Make `NodeBase` for an abstract base class, and make derived classes `NodeRoot`, `NodeInternal`, `NodeLeaf`.
  Something like:

```
    class NodeBase {
    };

    class NodeNonRoot;

    class NodeRoot : public NodeBase {
        std::shared_ptr<NodeNonRoot> left;
        std::shared_ptr<NodeNonRoot> right;
    };

    class NodeNonRoot : public NodeBase {
        std::weak_ptr<NodeBase> parent;
        std::size_t data;
    };

    class NodeInternal : public NodeNonRoot {
        std::shared_ptr<NodeNonRoot> left;
        std::shared_ptr<NodeNonRoot> right;
    };

    class NodeLeaf : public NodeNonRoot {
        std::weak_ptr<NodeLeaf> prev;
        std::weak_ptr<NodeLeaf> next;
    };
```

Cons : Complexity from the class hierarchy.

- ...couldn't think something else

Comment: Using shared_ptr and worrying about overhead from optional? Optional is rather lightweight compared to shared_ptr.

Answer (score 0):

Stop trying to use smart pointers for this, simplify:

```
struct Node {
    std::size_t value = 0;
    Node* left = nullptr;
    Node* right = nullptr;
};
```

That seems like enough.  You can use the same `left` and `right` pointers to build the doubly-linked list of leaves now, and as for the root not having a value, who cares, just don't use the `value` element there.  You need to keep track of which level of the tree you're on anyway.

Smart pointers aren't needed when creating node-based containers.  They aren't used in `std::list`, `std::map`, etc.  You can manage the lifetimes of elements yourself in the container as a whole, you don't need full-fledged lifetime relationships between the nodes so long as you don't let outside code create or destroy them.

Comment: Yes, this would be way simpler. Then I could ```delete``` ```Node*```s by iterating over hash maps at the destructor of ```XFastTrie```.

Comment: @frozenca: You won't even need to do that if each level is a `std::unordered_set<Node>` (stored by value).  Simply deleting the set will automatically delete the nodes.

Comment: Uh, that's not the case. I have to query the hash map by ```value``` contained in ```Node```.

Comment: That's OK, you can query a `std::unordered_set<Node>` by `value` either by creating a `Node` with null pointers and using a comparison function that only considers `value`, or by using the "transparent comparison" feature of C++20 if you have that: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find

Comment: The first reason I've decided to use smart pointers is that in this trie, ownerships of leaves are shared across multiple ancestors, so I can't simply recursively call ```delete left``` and ```delete right``` in a destructor of ```Node``` (which will give double-```delete``` crash). But fine, I have a hash map that contains each node exactly once. Good thing.

Comment: But then I have to define ```std::hash<Node>``` for using ```std::unordered_set<Node>```.

Comment: Right, specialize it to return the hash of the `value`.   Or use `unordered_map` if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Internal nodes do not contain values.  Typically, there will be many internal nodes beside the root node, and none of them will contain a value.

Comment: No, internal nodes contain prefixes of values. They are required for querying immediate hash tables to make iteration O(n lg lg u).